# Converting ArrayBuffer output from CSV to return one row in an optimal object in Scala

Tags: scala, csv

I have some Scala code that works, but I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to generate an object in the fashion i want for the return. I'm new to Scala and there's so many types I'm not sure what's the correct one for this use case and how to format it from the outputted data I get.

I want to be able to call this function like `getId('1.5')` and get an object back constructed from data in a CSV. The data in the CSV looks like:

```
,,ID,H2,H3,H4,H5,H6,H7,H8,H9,H10,H11,,
0.5,0.295,17.70%,2.70%,0.00%,0.02%,6.17%,0.01%,0.00%,0.00%,32.34%,41.05%,0.00%,,
1,0.34,18.64%,3.83%,0.00%,0.23%,7.67%,0.52%,0.00%,0.00%,30.57%,38.53%,0.00%,,
```

So outputted in a table

```
ID   H2     H3
0.5  0.295  17%
```

I want to be able to get a row with keys back as the return data. So, in a pseudo object after requesting `getId('0.5')` (using JSON as an example):

```
 {
   "H2": "0.295",
   "H3": "17%"
 }
```

I want to be able to easily use it elsewhere in my codebase so I could say `val x = getId('1.5')`. Then `x.H3` to get 17%. It'll mostly be used in loops. Here's what I have so far.

```
def getId(id: String) = {
  val filePath = getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("my_data.csv").getPath

  // each row is an array of strings (the columns in the csv file)
  val rows = ArrayBuffer[Array[String]]()

  // (1) read the csv data
  using(io.Source.fromFile(filePath)) { source =>
    for (line <- source.getLines) {
      rows += line.split(",").map(_.trim)
    }
  }

  // (2) print the results, here I'd actually be constructing that return object...
  for (row <- rows) {
    println(s"${row(0)} | ${row(2)} | ${row(3)} | ${row(4)}")
  }

  def using[A <: { def close(): Unit }, B](resource: A)(f: A => B): B =
    try {
      f(resource)
    } finally {
      resource.close()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this meet your needs? Made a few small tweaks to your code. You can get your data as a `Map[String, String]` and also put it into a more type-safe structure, e.g. a case class.

```
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.io.Source

object FromCSV {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val records = readDataFromFile
    val myRecord = records("0.5")
  }

  def readDataFromFile: Map[String, Record] = {
    val filePath = getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("my_data.csv").getPath
    val fieldSeparator = ","
    val records = mutable.Map.empty[String, Record]

    // each row is an array of strings (the columns in the csv file)
    val rows = mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[Map[String, String]]

    // (1) read the csv data
    using(Source.fromFile(filePath)) { source =>
      var lineNum = 0
      var colNames = Seq.empty[String]
      for (line <- source.getLines) {
        lineNum += 1
        lineNum match {
          case 1 => colNames = line.split(fieldSeparator)
          case _ => rows += (colNames zip line.split(fieldSeparator).map(_.trim)).toMap
        }
      }
    }

    // (2) print the results, here I'd actually be constructing that return object...
    for (row <- rows) {
      println(s"${row("ID")} | ${row("H2")} | ${row("H3")} | ${row("H4")}")
      val r = Record(row("ID"), row("H2"), row("H3"))
      records(r.id) = r
    }

    def using[A <: { def close(): Unit }, B](resource: A)(f: A => B): B =
      try {
        f(resource)
      } finally {
        resource.close()
      }
    records.toMap
  }
}

case class Record(id: String, h2: String, h3: String)
```